# How to extract the value form the below array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this.

```
Array (
    [0] => PHP
    [1] => ROR
    [2] => Python
    [3] => JAVA
)

Array (
    [0] => WP
    [1] => Drupal
    [2] => Joomla
    [3] => SpreeCommerce
)

Array (
    [0] => N2CMS
    [1] => Life Ray
    [2] => Magento
    [3] => Zen Cart
)
```

Here i need the the above array extract to this below format, the first array use like as column part and others array are use the columns value.

```
PHP = WP
ROR = Drupal
Python = Joomla
JAVA = SpreeCommerce

PHP = N2CMS
ROR = Life Ray
Python = Magento
JAVA = Zen Cart
```

Comment: have you tried this to your own??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough code, assuming all array have same length.

```
$array1=array("PHP","ROR","Python","Java");
    $array2=array("WP","Drupal","Joomla","SpreeCommerce");
    $array3=array("N2CMS","Life Ray","Magento","Zen Cart");

    for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
     echo $array1[$i]."=".$array2[$i]."<br>";
    }

    for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
     echo $array1[$i]."=".$array3[$i]."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a a try to **[array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-combine.php)**

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a simple function like this:

```
function mergerArray($array1, $array2)
{
    $retArray = array();
    // assumes that both are arrays and of equal length.
    for($i=0; $$i<count($array1); $i++)
    {
        $retArray[$array1[$i]]=$array2[$i];
    }

    return $retArray;
}

$mergedArray=mergerArray($keyMakingArray, $dataHoldingArray);

print_r($mergedArray);
```

Make sure to do all your checking of inputs before processing - ie, same number of elements, right data etc etc. I am not going to do that for you, this should be a good start allowing you as much flexibility as you need.